# Recalling a variable which value is the name of another variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd

I have written a script to pull specific event data from .csv logs.

> ```
> 2021_06_04 09:00.00, online, Serial#001, 50.10.10.10
> 2021_06_04 09:01.00, online, Serial#002, 50.10.10.11 
> 2021_06_04 09:01.00, read, Serial#002, apples, clear 
> 2021_06_04 09:01.00, online, Serial#003, 50.10.10.12 
> 2021_06_04 09:01.00, offline, Serial#001 
> 2021_06_04 09:02.00, read, Serial#002, bananas, clear 
> 2021_06_04 09:03.00, read, Serial#003, apples, reject 
> 2021_06_04 09:04.00, read, Serial#002, apples, clear
> 2021_06_04 09:05.00, read, Serial#003, apples, clear
> ```

First I find all machines that came online and store their IP addresses to variables named after their Serial Numbers

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=3,4" %%a in (
    'type "Log.csv"^|findstr "online"'
) do (
    set %%a=%%b
```

Now this has assigned variables as expected and as follows

> ```
> %Serial001% = 50.10.10.10
> %Serial002% = 50.10.10.11
> %Serial003% = 50.10.10.12
> ```

Now I want to find each "read" event per machine. Number of events are counted to create a "variable set"

```
set /p Search=Search: 

set EventCount = 0
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,3,5" %%a in (
    'type "Log.csv"^|findstr "read"^|findstr %search%'
) do (
    set /a EventCount+=1 
    call set EventTime[%%EventCount%%]=%%a 
    call set Machine[%%EventCount%%]=%%b
    call set Decision[%%BagCount%%]=%%c
)
set TotalCount=%EventCount%
```

Now I can display each data set, using 'choice' to scroll through the event count

**THE MILLION DOLLAR QUESTION!**

On the second line I want to add the Machine IP address which was stored in a variable, named after the machine...

`%%Machine%%` is outputting `%Serial#002%`

```
echo. Search:         %search%
echo. Machine:        !Machine[%EventCount%]!    on   %%Machine%%
echo  Decision:       !Decision[%BagCount%]!   @   !EventTime[%EventCount%]!
echo. 
echo. %EventCount%  of  %TotalCount%
```

expected output

> ```
> Search:         Apples 
> Machine:        Serial#002    on    50.10.10.10
> Decision:       Clear   @   2021_06_04 09:01.00
> 1  of  4
> ```

How do I display the IP address by expanding the variable that is named after a variable...

I've tried all combinations of delayed expansion without luck. I want to recall this IP address for other functions also, not just display purposes.

Any direction would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

You already knew the trick - use `CALL %%...%%`

```
call echo. Machine: %%!Machine[%EventCount%]!%%    on   %%Machine%%
```

Btw.
This block:

```
call set EventTime[%%EventCount%%]=%%a 
call set Machine[%%EventCount%%]=%%b
call set Decision[%%BagCount%%]=%%c
```

should be changed to

```
set EventTime[!EventCount!]=%%a 
set Machine[!EventCount!]=%%b
set Decision[!BagCount!]=%%c
```

Because, `CALL` is much slower.

The `CALL` command works, because it restarts the batch parser and one more percent expansion occurs, but it also has some unwanted side effects, like doubling/removing of carets and evaluation of special characters like `&|<>`.

Therefore a line like

```
call set EventTime[%%EventCount%%]=%%a
```

would fail, if `%%a` contains `Cat&Dog`

Comment: Be sure to add `SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`.

Comment: worked a treat, thanks Jeb! now I'll do some reading on why as don't completely understand the purpose for 'call'.